# Query to select record ignoring duplicates

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates, unique

I need to return a list of students with the respective task results, however, students can repeat the task, this means that there are duplicates. I want to get the first result but I want to get the first result from all the students in the class.

My current query that returns all the results including duplicates is:

```
SELECT student_id, attempt_id, task_score
FROM Attempt JOIN SetPaper ON Attempt.paper_id = SetPaper.paper_id
WHERE SetPaper.task_id = {X} AND class_id = {Y} AND task_status = "complete";
```

*Where 'X' and 'Y' are predetermined variables.*

This currently will return:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| student_id | attempt_id | task_score |
+------------+------------+------------+
|    X0000   |      1     |     70     |
|    X0001   |      2     |     40     |
|    X0001   |      3     |     50     |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

This is because in this case student 'X0001' has attempted and completed the task twice. However, I want it in the format:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| student_id | attempt_id | task_score |
+------------+------------+------------+
|    X0000   |      1     |     70     |
|    X0001   |      2     |     40     |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

So that it only gets their first attempts results.

I have tried using DISTINCT(student_id) but that still gets the other results if I want to return more that just the student id's.

Thanks,

Ryan.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Sorry, I don't use SQL a lot, could you explain why that is the correct way of formatting? as the way we're shown was to use commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- DeveloperAndreaCook wishes to perform a JOIN query that returns distinct results on a table.
- This can be done using MySQL GROUP BY

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- MySQL 5.x
- Distinct results from a SELECT JOIN Query

#### Problem

- **Scenario:** Developer wishes to perform a JOIN query that returns distinct results

#### Solution

- use GROUP BY Expression

#### Sample Data

```
qqperson
  +----+---------+
  | id | fname   |
  +----+---------+
  |  1 | alice   |
  |  2 | bobby   |
  |  3 | charlie |
  |  4 | danny   |
  |  5 | eddie   |
  |  6 | freddy  |
  +----+---------+
```

qqtask
  +----+------------+-----------+-------------+
  | id | taskname   | taskscore | qqperson_id |
  +----+------------+-----------+-------------+
  |  1 | action-a   | 40        |           1 |
  |  2 | action-aa  | 50        |           1 |
  |  3 | action-b   | 40        |           2 |
  |  4 | action-c   | 50        |           3 |
  |  5 | action-d   | 50        |           4 |
  |  6 | action-aaa | 60        |           1 |
  +----+------------+-----------+-------------+

#### Example00

- example00 (query) sample query that includes unwanted duplicates

  ```
  SELECT
    'x' AS `x`
    ,`qqperson`.`id` AS `person_id`
    ,`qqperson`.`fname` AS `fname`
    ,`qqtask`.`qqperson_id` AS `qqperson_id`
    ,`qqtask`.`taskscore` AS `taskscore`
    ,`qqtask`.`id` AS `task_id`
  FROM
    (
      `qqperson`
      JOIN `qqtask` ON (
        (
          `qqtask`.`qqperson_id` = `qqperson`.`id`
        )
      )
    )
  ```
- example00 (result)

  ```
  x    | person_id | fname   | qqperson_id | taskscore | task_id
  x    | 1         | alice   | 1           | 40        | 1      
  x    | 1         | alice   | 1           | 50        | 2      
  x    | 2         | bobby   | 2           | 40        | 3      
  x    | 3         | charlie | 3           | 50        | 4      
  x    | 4         | danny   | 4           | 50        | 5      
  x    | 1         | alice   | 1           | 60        | 6
  ```

#### Example01

- example01 (query) ignore duplicates with `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY`

  ```
  SELECT
    'x' AS `x`
    ,`qqperson`.`id` AS `person_id`
    ,`qqperson`.`fname` AS `fname`
    ,`qqtask`.`qqperson_id` AS `qqperson_id`
    ,`qqtask`.`taskscore` AS `taskscore`
    ,`qqtask`.`id` AS `task_id`
  FROM
    (
      `qqperson`
      JOIN `qqtask` ON (
        (
          `qqtask`.`qqperson_id` = `qqperson`.`id`
        )
      )
    )

  GROUP BY
    `qqperson`.`id`

  ORDER BY
    `qqperson`.`id`
  ```
- example01 (result)

  ```
  x    | person_id | fname   | qqperson_id | taskscore | task_id
  x    | 1         | alice   | 1           | 40        | 1      
  x    | 2         | bobby   | 2           | 40        | 3      
  x    | 3         | charlie | 3           | 50        | 4      
  x    | 4         | danny   | 4           | 50        | 5
  ```

#### Pitfalls

- The `ORDER BY` clause will affect the output of the query
- sql_mode=only_full_group_by

#### See also

- [Error related to only_full_group_by when executing a query in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38551525/42223

Comment: my final select statement that works is this: `SELECT student_id, attempt_id, task_score FROM Attempt JOIN SetPaper ON Attempt.paper_id = SetPaper.paper_id GROUP BY student_id;`